# Comparing a user-drawn shape to a preset shape (iphone game)

Tags: iphone, comparison, shapes

For my iphone game program, I need to take what the user draws and see what it is. For example, I need to see if it is a square, circle, star, or triangle. Are there tools available for something like this? I don't really know where to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the [$1 recognizer](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/) if you only need single-stroke shapes. [GLGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/preble/GLGestureRecognizer) is an Objective-C implementation, though I haven't tried it out.

If you need multiple strokes, try the [$N variant](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/ndollar.html), which also has an [iOS implementation](https://github.com/britg/MultistrokeGestureRecognizer-iOS). I've used $N in a Flex project before and had pretty good results.

Comment: The $1 recognizer looks like the answer to my problems. Thank you, kind sir!